# Neither success or error callback executed in ajax request to Rest API

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a rest api and am trying to invoke it from a restclient with an ajax query but have run in to a bit of trouble. I've no idea why this ajax query isn't working as the data I'm using to execute it seems to be fine and the alerts in the code all work except for the ones in the callbacks.

Any suggestions appreciated.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#user_delete').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var user_id = $(this).attr('user');
      var deleteurl = 'http://localhost:5000/library/user/'+user_id;
      alert(user_id)
      alert(deleteurl)
        $.ajax({
        url: deleteurl,
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function(data) {
          alert(data)
        },
        error: function(data){
          alert(data)
        }
      });
    });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: Are you sure the request actually is made? Double check your browser's network tab.

Comment: @tstrand66 that's true, but note that the OP is not using `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()` or `jqXHR.complete()` in the example.

Comment: Could it be a problem with the way I did the api as opposed to the actual ajax request? Even .always() doesn't work

Comment: @Bryan That would mean the code never runs. Again, can you see it in the browser's network tab or not? Set a breakpoint, step through the code, see what happens. The code you show here definitely works, so the problem must be somewhere else.